# how to print alphabets for numbering using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to print alphabets for marking options of questions using `ng-repeat` directive in Angular.

```
<div ng-repeat="options in $root.options">
  //print alphabets in sequence here//:{{options}}
</div>
```

`$root.options` have 4 option, now i want it to be printed like

**A: option 1**

**B: option 2**

**C: option 3**

**D: option 4**

PS: I am not using HTML list neither I am planning to.

Comment: Good question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to create a string in your `$scope` as follows:

```
$scope.alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
```

You can then use `track by $index` in your `ng-repeat` to access letters from the string as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="options in $root.options track by $index">
  {{ alphabet[$index] }}: {{ options }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

First define all the alphabets:

```
$scope.letterArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    $scope.letterArray.push(String.fromCharCode(65 + i));
}
```

And then use it:

```
<div ng-repeat="options in $root.options">
    {{letterArray[$index]}}: option {{$option}}
</div>
```

**See it working below:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module("sa", []);

myApp.controller("foo", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.letterArray = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    $scope.letterArray.push(String.fromCharCode(65 + i));
  }

  $scope.options = [{
    name: "hello foo"
  }, {
    name: "hello bar"
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="foo">
  <div ng-repeat="option in options">
    {{letterArray[$index]}}: {{option.name}} {{$index}}
  </div>
</div>
```